# Cordova 6.0 resets the application for every run

Tags: android, cordova

Recently I upgraded my cordova installation from `5.3` to `6.0`. One weird thing I found after upgrade is my application data is reset every time I  emulate android application.

E.g. I am saving some data in my localstorage e.g "first-run" to configure application. Earlier it used to keep value of "first-run" once I set it till I uninstall the application from emulator. Now for every time I run application on emulator I don't get value for the key. However if I run application by tapping on app icon, application runs as expected.

Any one have any idea why this is happening? I doubt Cordova is uninstalling the application before installing again while build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A was also having this issue with the version 5.1.0 of the android platform.

This has been fixed with the version 5.1.1 :

***CB-10157 Uninstall app from device/emulator only when signed apk is already installed***

So to fix it, either remove/add the android platform :

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android
```

or upgrade the platform : (I personnally prefer to remove it)

```
cordova platform update android
```